# How to change database engine in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am working in SSMS 2012.  I recently discovered that 2012 built-in functions like `TRY_CONVERT` and `DATEFROMPARTS` are not recognized by my particular instance.  So, I checked my database engine (at least, I think it's the engine I'm checking) via `SELECT @@VERSION`, and it returned Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.01.1600.22 (X64).  If this is an engine problem (i.e., I'm not using the 2012 engine), how do I update / change the engine to the 2012 version?

Comment: Buy or download the appropriate version and upgrade the server?

Comment: You are confusing *Version* with *Compatibility level*. While the latter can be set back from a newer version, that is not your circumstance; you will have to buy and upgrade to the desired version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 3 factors as play here than can confuse you:

1. SSMS Version: SSMS is only the GUI to access SQL Server. Later version of SSMS can access earlier version of the SQL Server Engine. The fact that you are running SSMS 2012 doesn't mean you will get access to new functions in SQL Server 2012.
2. SQL Server Engine Version: **I think this is your problem**. The result you got clearly indicate it's 2008.
3. Compatibility level: you can run a newer SQL Server Engine as if it's an older one. So you can run SQL Server 2012 as 2008 or even 2005. In that case, even though you engine supports these new functions, the compatibility level prevents you from using them.

I think your problem is that you are accessing SQL Server 2008 through SSMS 2012. Get the proper version of SQL Server through MSDN, SQL Server Express (free) or DreamSpark( if you are a student).